# Differentiate between robotic and human keyboardinput

Tags: java, input, awtrobot, selectall

I want to "Select all" via a robot pressing the keys Control and A, but i dont want the keyboardListener to notice it as input.
Is there another way to use "Select all" or a way to differentiate between the two input types?

Edit: I'm using the JNativeHook NativeKeyboardListener, not the normal one, thought I'd point that out, maybe it has some special abilities. :)

Comment: What do you mean by *"but i dont want the keyboardListener to notice it as input"*?  Wouldn't that defeat the purpose?  Also remember Ctrl+A is basically "press" ctrl, "press" A, "release" A", "release" ctrl...

Comment: The purpose for the keyboardListener is to record every human input and write it down (im writing kind of like a keylogger, educational purposes only of course). The button to to "select all" is on the hidden JFrame. And since the user doesnt know about it, its not his input, only mine if I'd use it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  You'd have to turn of your key logger, press ctrl+A and re-enable the key logger

Comment: Haven't thought about that yet. Not a bad idear. I think that might be my backdoor ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just set the selected range on the appropriate control. No keyboard is needed for this, so it won't be handled by a keyboard listener.

Comment: What do you mean by that, would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: I don't know what control are you using, but for example method like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll%28%29  But maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: That would be perfect! And how would i call that method for a JTextPane on a JFrame?

Comment: Well, for JTextPane you have http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectionStart%28int%29  and setSelectionEnd.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject input but in order for it to be recognized by the application layer it needs to propagate up through the input stack and thus will be recognized by the keyboardlistener.

Perhaps there is another way to perform a select all programmatically without injecting keyboard input.

Comment: Yes, I thought the same. I googled for the past 30 mins for another way to use the select all, but could not find any other way.